# nginx ingress on kubernetes url routing to host

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

How should my rule look like : 
if want to support dynamic url mapping to services

```
/a should map to service service-a
/b should map to service service-b
/cccc should map to service service-cccc
```

Note : services can be added dynamically

hence afte r say 10 minutes. we now have

```
/dddd should map to service service-dddd
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically you keep appending new path to $.spec.rules[x].http.paths, where x is the index of the host which you intend to add path on.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  namespace: my-namespace
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    # and other annotations you need..
  #labels:
     # if you need labels
spec:
  rules:
  - host: "your.hostname"
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /a
        backend:
          serviceName: service-a
          servicePort: 443 # say your service runs on 443
      - path: /b
        backend:
          serviceName: service-b
          servicePort: 443 # say your service runs on 443
      - path: /cccc
        backend:
          serviceName: service-cccc
          servicePort: 443 # say your service runs on 443
```

Comment: can there be a wildcard for path to service mapping

Comment: Nope. In native kubernetes yaml you cannot do that. And for your use case above specifically your best bet is to use script to do it. However, I do think you should have a ingress object defined for each service -- that's what people do and it just works. In that way, you will be able to utilize templating tool like kustomize(lightweight) or the notorious helm. And you will use some "wildcard" in your yaml template, and the tools gonna fill in the value during runtime.

Comment: can we hot reload nginx .. which means that i don't want to restart nginx

Comment: you don`t have to restart nginx